# Glob for file suffix not matching

Tags: bash, shell, glob

I have some Unix command finding mov-files that have a corresponding jpg file:

```
find . -name '*.[Mm][Oo][Vv]' -exec sh -c '
for mov; do
  for jpg in "${mov%.*}".[Jj][Pp][Gg]; do
    if test -f "$jpg"; then
      echo "$mov" 
    fi
    break
  done
done' sh {} +
```

The current code just searches for .jpg (or uppercase) as file extension, but I need to extend this to also support files that ends with ".jpeg".

I modified the code to say:

```
for jpg in "${mov%.*}".[Jj][Pp][Ee]?[Gg]; do
```

which I believed should make it possible to have an optional "E or e", but this does not work.

I was able to use this instead

```
for jpg in "${mov%.*}".[Jj][Pp]*[Gg]; do
```

which is not very safe because it will accept a lot more tha e and E in that position.

Any ideas how to modify expression to add the optional e/E in the reg exp?

Comment: Please don't use the bash tag when your code is actually running with `sh` instead of bash -- they're two different shells; even when bash itself is started under the `sh` name, it disables some features for better compatibility -- and on many operating systems, including Debian and Ubuntu, `sh` is not provided by `bash` at all; in those particular cases it's `dash`, Debian's take on the [Almquist shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell).

Comment: `?` means "make the prior character optional" in _regex_ syntax, but in (unextended) _glob_ syntax it means "match any one character".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `extglob` feature suffices for this. Running `shopt -s extglob` when using `bash` (**not** `sh`) will let you use `?([Ee])` to refer to zero-or-one instances of `[Ee]`.

Even better, while we're setting `shopt` flags, we can set `nocaseglob` so you can use `*.jp?(e)g`, without the explicit character classes. (The `find` equivalent for this is changing `-name` to `-iname`, which the following does in addition).

```
find . -iname '*.mov' -exec bash -c '
shopt -s extglob nocaseglob
for mov; do
  for jpg in "${mov%.*}".jp?(e)g; do
    if test -f "$jpg"; then
      printf "%s\n" "$mov" 
    fi
    break
  done
done' bash {} +
```

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive answer. I will try this. 

But is there a reason why my original try did not work?

Comment: @Ziggy000 The original didn't work because you're trying to use regular expression syntax, but `-name` doesn't take a regex pattern, it takes a wildcard (or "glob") pattern. The two pattern types look similar, but have some huge differences; in particular, `?` means completely different things between them. `extglob` enables extensions to the glob syntax that make it as capable as a true regex pattern, but (again) with very different syntax. (And BTW there are also a bunch of variants of the regex syntax, and using the wrong dialect is another common source of trouble.)

Comment: @GordonDavisson I guess this is not relevant for the -name parameter? The -name is only used to find the mov files. But your comment is still valid like a principle.

Comment: @Ziggy000 Right. Sorry, I was thinking about the `-name` pattern, but it's the shell wildcard in the `for` statement that's relevant. `-name` and the shell wildcard both use glob syntax, but `extglob` only affects shell patterns, not `find` (so `-name` will always use standard globs, not extended).